# C#: How can Dictionary<K,V> implement ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>> without having Add(KeyValuePair<K,V>)?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, interface

Looking at `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it clearly implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, but doesn't have the required "`void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)`" function.

This can also be seen when trying to initialize a `Dictionary` like this:

```
private const Dictionary<string, int> PropertyIDs = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string,int>("muh", 2)
};
```

which fails with

> No overload for method 'Add' takes '1' arguments

Why is that so?

Comment: {new KeyValuePair<string,int>("muh", 2)}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The expected API is to add via the two argument `Add(key,value)` method (or the `this[key]` indexer); as such, it uses explicit interface implementation to provide the `Add(KeyValuePair<,>)` method.

If you use the `IDictionary<string, int>` interface instead, you will have access to the missing method (since you can't hide anything on an interface).

Also, with the collection initializer, note that you can use the alternative syntax:

```
Dictionary<string, int> PropertyIDs = new Dictionary<string, int> {
  {"abc",1}, {"def",2}, {"ghi",3}
}
```

which uses the `Add(key,value)` method.

Comment: d'oh, should have known that!

Answer (score 9):

Some interface methods are implemented [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(VS.71).aspx). If you use reflector you can see the explicitly implemented methods, which are:

```
void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair);
bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair);
void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index);
bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair);
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator();
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index);
void IDictionary.Add(object key, object value);
bool IDictionary.Contains(object key);
IDictionaryEnumerator IDictionary.GetEnumerator();
void IDictionary.Remove(object key);
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't implement `ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` directly. It implements `IDictionary<K,V>`.

`IDictionary<K,V>` derives from `ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question - it must (to be valid) still *have* such an Add method - it juts happens to be an explicit implementation rather than part of the public class API.