# Creating a constant Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary, constants

What is the most efficient way to create a **constant** (never changes at runtime) mapping of `string`s to `int`s?

I've tried using a [const Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268064/c-how-can-dictionarykv-implement-icollectionkeyvaluepairkv-without-having-addke), but that didn't work out.

I could implement a [immutable wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002/does-c-have-a-way-of-giving-me-an-immutable-dictionary) with appropriate semantics, but that still doesn't seem totally right.

---

For those who have asked, I'm implementing [IDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in a generated class and am looking for a way to make the columnName lookup into my array of descriptors.

I wasn't aware (typo when testing! d'oh!) that switch accepts strings, so that's what I'm gonna use. Thanks!

Comment: there is a solution here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066708/readonly-keyword-does-not-make-a-list-readonly

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Creating a truly compile-time generated constant dictionary in C# is not really a straightforward task. Actually, none of the answers here really achieve that.

There is one solution though which meets your requirements, although not necessarily a nice one; remember that according to the C# specification, switch-case tables are compiled to constant hash jump tables. That is, they are constant dictionaries, not a series of if-else statements. So consider a switch-case statement like this:

```
switch (myString)
{
   case "cat": return 0;
   case "dog": return 1;
   case "elephant": return 3;
}
```

This is exactly what you want. And yes, I know, it's ugly.

Comment: It's generated code anyways, has good performance characteristics, can be compile-time computed, and has other nice properties for my use case too. I'll be doing it like this!

Comment: just be careful that returning non-value types, even like this, will break your classes immutability.

Comment: switch-case is awesome, until you need to "foreach" through the values.

Comment: I came here thinking I needed a constant dictionary to help map data between analogous classes. Instead, what I needed was a method that contained a switch! In addition, I can now require the method in an interface for any future data mapping classes. This answer was spot on.

Comment: It lacks a lot of nice functions that Dictionaries have.

Comment: @TomAnderson: The construct will behave as immutable if the returned items are value types (mutable or not), or if they are immutable class objects.

Answer (score 41):

There are precious few immutable collections in the current framework. I can think of one relatively pain-free option in .NET 3.5:

Use `Enumerable.ToLookup()` - the [`Lookup<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class is immutable (but multi-valued on the rhs); you can do this from a `Dictionary<,>` quite easily:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> ids = new Dictionary<string, int> {
      {"abc",1}, {"def",2}, {"ghi",3}
    };
    ILookup<string, int> lookup = ids.ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    int i = lookup["def"].Single();
```

Answer (score 19):

I am not sure why no one mentioned this but in C# for things that I cannot assign const, I use static read-only properties.

Example:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> NewDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            { "Reference1", Array1 },
            { "Reference2", Array2 },
            { "Reference3", Array3 },
            { "Reference4", Array4 },
            { "Reference5", Array5 }
        };
```

Comment: because the contents of the dictionary are still mutable, and it is allocated at runtime.

Answer (score 18):

```
enum Constants
{
    Abc = 1,
    Def = 2,
    Ghi = 3
}

...

int i = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Constants), "Def");
```

Comment: Interesting idea! I'm wondering how good the Parse() call performs. I fear only a profiler can answer that one.

Answer (score 11):

This is the closest thing you can get to a "CONST Dictionary":

```
public static int GetValueByName(string name)
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "bob": return 1;
        case "billy": return 2;
        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

The compiler will be smart enough to build the code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 9):

If using 4.5+ Framework I would use ReadOnlyDictionary (also ReadOnly Collection for lists) to do readonly mappings/constants. It's implemented in the following way.

```
static class SomeClass
{
    static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<string,int> SOME_MAPPING 
        = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string,int>(
            new Dictionary<string,int>()
            {
                { "One", 1 },
                { "Two", 2 }
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: `private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _yourDictionaryName = 
            new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
                { "One",1 }, { "Two",2 }, { "Three",3 },               
        };`
This is how I did it.

Comment: @SanketSonavane a `readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` isn't equivalent to a `ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. In fact, they way they are "read only" is pretty much opposite of each other. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/v0l4aA.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use namespaces or classes to nest your values?  It may be imperfect, but it is very clean.

```
public static class ParentClass
{
    // here is the "dictionary" class
    public static class FooDictionary
    {
        public const string Key1 = "somevalue";
        public const string Foobar = "fubar";
    }
}
```

Now you can access .ParentClass.FooDictionary.Key1, etc.

Comment: Because this does not implement the IDataErrorInfo interface.

Answer (score 3):

As of C# 8, the [new switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) is the cleanest way to achieve the result:

```
int value = inputString switch {
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    _ => -1
};
```

or as a function

```
int GetValue(string inputString) => inputString switch {
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    _ => -1
};
```

It is more concise that the "old" one:

```
int value = -1;
switch (inputString){
    case "one": value=1; break;
    case "two": value=2; break;
}
```

The difference in performance of the old and new one can vary across different compilers

Comment: This is certainly neater to type, but can you explain/show how (much) this is faster (in CPU time) than a regular switch statement? I would assume(!) that a good(!) compiler could create exactly the same CLR instructions for both of your examples.

Comment: @DavidSchmitt you're right, I have drawn the conclusion about the speed while using Codewars' default compiler, when I re-run the same things in Linqpad there was no significant difference

Answer (score 2):

Just another idea since I am binding to a winforms combobox:

```
public enum DateRange {
    [Display(Name = "None")]
    None = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Today")]
    Today = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Tomorrow")]
    Tomorrow = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Yesterday")]
    Yesterday = 3,
    [Display(Name = "Last 7 Days")]
    LastSeven = 4,
    [Display(Name = "Custom")]
    Custom = 99
    };

int something = (int)DateRange.None;
```

To get the int value from the display name [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225729/enum-value-from-display-name):

```
public static class EnumHelper<T>
{
    public static T GetValueFromName(string name)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                if (attribute.Name == name)
                {
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == name)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("name");
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var z = (int)EnumHelper<DateRange>.GetValueFromName("Last 7 Days");
```

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be any standard immutable interface for dictionaries, so creating a wrapper seems like the only reasonable option, unfortunately.

**Edit**: Marc Gravell found the ILookup that I missed - that will allow you to at least avoid creating a new wrapper, although you still need to transform the Dictionary with .ToLookup().

If this is a need constrained to a specific scenario, you might be better off with a more business-logic-oriented interface:

```
interface IActiveUserCountProvider
{
    int GetMaxForServer(string serverName);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _myCollection = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "A", 1 }, { "B", 2 }, { "C", 3 } };

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>> MyCollection
    {
        get { return _myCollection.AsEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because this is quite expensive compared to the available alternatives under the specified conditions.

Comment: Also because this doesn't even compile

Comment: @AustinWBryan yes it compiles