# readonly keyword does not make a List<> ReadOnly?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have the following code in a public static class:

```
public static class MyList
{
    public static readonly SortedList<int, List<myObj>> CharList;
    // ...etc.
}
```

.. but even using `readonly` I can still add items to the list from another class:

```
MyList.CharList[100] = new List<myObj>() { new myObj(30, 30) };
```

or

```
MyList.CharList.Add(new List<myObj>() { new myObj(30, 30) });
```

Is there a way to make the thing read only without changing the implementation of CharList (it'll break some stuff)?
If I do have to change the implementation (to make it non-changeable), what would be the best way?
I need it to be List<T, T>, so ReadOnlyCollection won't do

Comment: Return a [List(Of T).AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx)

Answer (score 62):

The modifier [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) means that the value cannot be *assigned* except in the declaration or constructor. It does *not* mean that the assigned object becomes immutable.

If you want your  object to be immutable, you must use a type that is immutable. The type [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) that you mentioned is an example of a immutable collection. See this related question for how to achieve the same for dictionaries:

- [Is there a read-only generic dictionary available in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net)

Comment: The question mentions "I need it to be List<T, T>, so ReadOnlyCollection won't do", and there is no `ReadOnlyDictionary` that I am aware of.

Comment: See the link I added "Is there a read-only generic dictionary available in .NET?"

Comment: Huh. As hinted in an answer in that question, as it turns out, .NET 4.5 does have a `ReadOnlyDictionary` already. Cool.

Comment: @hvd: Nice find, I missed that. Did you vote it up? The more votes it has, the more likely people will see it.

Answer (score 3):

The readonly modifier just gaurantees that the variable 'CharList' cannot be re-assigned to something else from outside of the class constructor. You need to create your own dictionary structure that doesn't have a public Add() method.

```
class ImmutableSortedList<T, T1> 
{
    SortedList<T, T1> mSortedList;

    public ImmutableSortedList(SortedList<T, T1> sortedList) // can only add here (immutable)
    {
        this.mSortedList = sortedList; 
    }

    public implicit operator ImmutableSortedList<T, T1>(SortedList<T, T1> sortedList)
    {
        return new ImmutableSortedList<T, T1>(sortedList); 
    }
}
```

Or, if you truly can't change the implementation, make the SortedList private and add your own methods that control access to it:

```
class MyList
{
    // private now
    readonly SortedList<int, List<myObj>> CharList;

    // public indexer
    public List<myObj> this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.CharList[index]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The List have the [AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method that return a read only list should be what you want.

Comment: But the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` does not.

Comment: It returns a ReadOnlyCollection<T>