# C# readonly get accessor

Tags: c#, get, readonly, accessor

Code:-
(Note:- here I'm using read-only word means that property has only get accessor.)

```
Class Test
{
    public List<string> list {get;}
    public string name{get;}

    public Test ()
    {
       list =new List<string>();
    }
}

Main()
{
    Test test =new Test();
    test.list.add("c#"); //no error 
    test.name="Jhon"; //here I get compilation because property name is read-only
}
```

If you see above snippet. Test class contain two property which is name and list. In main method I'm creating object of test class to access these properties. So if you see if I try to set value to name property then I'll get compilation error because name property is read only. Similarly if you see another property 'list' that is also read-only if I use add property of List class then without error I'm able to add in list.
 So I'm not getting how this happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066708/readonly-keyword-does-not-make-a-list-readonly

Comment: @LennartStoop - no, same answer/explanation but very different question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman would not say very different, the sample code clearly shows an item is being added to a list (and not accessed directly)

Comment: Yes, but the read only mechanisms are very different. It's not about the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding of how a "read only" property would work.

If your code looked like this:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.list.Add("c#"); //no error because you are not 'setting' the object
test.list = new List<string>(); //Error here because you ARE setting the object
```

`Add()` is just a method of a `List<T>`, you are *modifying* the object not setting the property to something else.

If you want your *collection* to be "read only" you can use the [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.  You can manage a `private` list internally and only expose through the `public ReadOnlyCollection`.  Your desired functionality was never made clear so I wouldn't know what to suggest beyond what I have.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `set` would refer to setting the `List` *object*, the actual instance of the collection. The `List` itself, when returned, is not readonly. If you want it to be readonly, you can do something like:

```
private List<string> list;

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> List {get => list.AsReadOnly()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in case of a `string` you return a *copy* of the instance - you can not assign to it.

[Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

In case of a `List<T>` you return a *reference* to an instance, which is not constant in your case - it is possible to change it.

To prove that yourself, you can do something like :

```
class Test 
{
    private string val; 
    public ref string Val {get {return ref val;}}
}


void Main()
{
    Test t = new Test();
    t.Val = "a";

    Console.WriteLine("t.Val is - " + t.Val);
}
```

Observe special `ref` keyword I used in `string` property, to denote that `string` *reference* has to be returned and *not a copy* of it.

[C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types (Joseph Albahari)](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> list {get;}
```

That means, it causes the error if you do the same action with `name`.

```
test.list = new List<string>();
```

`test.list` to get the `list` object and you call the method Add of the  `list` object. So it's normal.