# How can I combine a method and a dictionary used by the method for lookups?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a constant Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268084/creating-a-constant-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

I currently have:

```
    public string GetRefStat(int pk) {
        return RefStat[pk];
    }
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> RefStat =
    new Dictionary<int, int> 
    {
        {1,2},
        {2,3},
        {3,5} 
    };
```

This works but the only time I use the RefStat dictionary is when it is called by GetRefStat.

Is there a way I can combine the method and the dictionary?

Comment: are those both not combined in a class already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 public string GetRefStat(int pk) 
{ 
    return new Dictionary<int, int>   
    {  
        {1,2},  
        {2,3},  
        {3,5}   
    }[pk]; 
}
```

Comment: Creating a new dictionary object for every lookup is a terrible idea.

Comment: It is typical for such functions to be called once for type instance. So it can be not so terrible as you think.

Comment: Typical? The OP wanted a compile-time defined mapping between a set of numbers. You're wasting cycles with object instantiation, hashing, creating buckets and garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can init the dictionary in the type's constructor. You can then change method `GetRefStat` to a property. So the meta code may look like this

```
class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> RefStat {get;private set;}

    Foo()
    {
        RefStat = new Dictionary<int, int> 
        {
            {1,2},
            {2,3},
            {3,5} 
        };
    }
}
```

And usage

```
Foo f = new Foo();
var item = f.RefStat[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make an extension method and then all dictionaries can use the function.  I am going to assume that `GetRefStat` will be more than simply grabbing a value from a dictionary with a key:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetRefStat<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) 
    {
        return dictionary[key];
    }
}
```

Then all dictionaries can call it like:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int> 
    {
        {1,2},
        {2,3},
        {3,5} 
    };
var value = dictionary.GetRefStat(2)
```

If this dictionary is a bunch of constants then this answer is overkill.  Just use `if/else` or `switch`.