# Will compiler optimize collections initialization?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, compiler-optimization

Will compiler optimize this code or will the collection be initialized after each method call?

```
private string Parse(string s)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"a", "x"},
        {"b", "y"}
    };

    return dict[s];
}
```

If answer is negative, I recommend to use this solution: [Creating a constant Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268084/creating-a-constant-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Well the GC will prolly dispose it after the method scope, though it's non deterministic.

Comment: Can you explain why you think a compiler may optimize this and how?

Comment: @CodeCaster Why:compiler can depend on specific .NET classes, and this situation can be detected easily. How: making it static, for example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When such a question arises and you're not sure what the answer is, it's always good to look "under the hood".

This is the IL the compiler generated with the optimizer turned on:

```
Parse:
IL_0000:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String,System.String>..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0006:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0007:  ldstr       "a"
IL_000C:  ldstr       "x"
IL_0011:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String,System.String>.Add
IL_0016:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0017:  ldstr       "b"
IL_001C:  ldstr       "y"
IL_0021:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String,System.String>.Add
IL_0026:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0027:  stloc.0     // dict
IL_0028:  ldloc.0     // dict
IL_0029:  ldarg.1     
IL_002A:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String,System.String>.get_Item
IL_002F:  ret
```

As you can see, it calls `newobj` to allocate the `Dictionary<K,V>` *each time*, loads both locals and calls `Dictionary.Add` each time on both of them (which is the syntactical sugar equivalent of calling `Add`) . It has no intimate knowledge with the type in order to cache the objects creation.

Comment: The result of this inspection might change at any time. It is much better to reason that the compiler is not allowed to do this ever.

Comment: @usr You're right, that's why i stated the compiler has no intimate knowledge with the type. Although saying *"inspection might change at any time"* is a rather general statement, which can be true for any of the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

No, it will not. It has no intrinsic knowledge of what a `Dictionary` is. For the compiler, it's just a normal class, so it doesn't know it *could* reuse the instance in this particular case.

This would be the proper way to do this:

```
public class Something
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"a", "x"},
        {"b", "y"}
    }

    private string Parse(string s)
    {
        return _dict[s];
    }
}
```

This approach works because you know what the object does and you also know it's never modified.

Remember the following syntax:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "x"},
    {"b", "y"}
}
```

Is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("a", "x");
dict.Add("b", "y");
```

The only requirement to make this work with *any* class, is for the class to

- Implement `IEnumerable`
- Have a public `Add` method.

You suggested to use a `switch` statement, but the `Dictionary` approach can be more flexible. Consider for instance you could want to use a different equality comparer (like `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`). It's better to let the `Dictionary` handle this using the proper comparer than using something like `switch(value.ToLowerInvariant())`.

Comment: There are many examples when compiler depends on specific .NET classes. Why not `Dictionary`?

Comment: @astef why should it? What's so special about a `Dictionary`? Why not a `HashSet` then? or `OrderedDictionary`, or `ConditionalWeakTable`? This would be endless. It's better to have only a few special known cases (`Task<T>` comes to mind)

Comment: What so special in `Add` method to replace it with initializer? Honestly, I don't know. Just asking )

Comment: @astef it's simply a convention for developer convenience. When the compiler sees an initializer it will replace it with `Add` calls but there's nothing special about the method itself. It could do anything. The compiler doesn't care, it just provides syntactic sugar for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, C# as it stands won't 'optimize' this in any way - and I seriously doubt that will ever be the case.

While you may argue that this particular code could be optimized, it is in fact a border case, which is not that trivial to determine at compile time. To give you a counter example - what if one of your string literals was a member of another class? What if you had a custom dictionary (and there is no special handling for the existing dictionary class) which did something funky in its constructor?

Comment: "what if one of your string literals was a member of another class?" - can't see anything bad in it, can you explain? You right about custom dictionaries, but what about usual dictionary. It is already coupled with a compiler (see initializer)

Comment: Well imagine you had `new Dictinary<String, String> { { "x", SOME_CLASS.MEMBER } }`. Now when `SOME_CLASS.MEMBER` changes, a consequent call to `Parse` should use the new value - so it can't be optimized.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding reference types in C#. Possible optimization is just making dictionary a static field - it will be initialized only once. What problem do you see in this case?

Comment: Do I? Here's a quick and dirty example then to illustrate my point: http://pastebin.com/pYvXe1bc

Comment: Now I get what you mean. Of course, this case with run-time value defining can't be optimized. Though, it can be easily detected

Comment: I disagree - what if the value was for example readonly? What if it was a fixed lambda that returns a const literal? Obviously it's doable - there's no magic there, but there's a ton of scenarios to consider - just to do something that would be counterintuitive to your average dev. As I've mentioned earlier - the compiler can't try to out-think the developer - if you're instantiating a dictionary on each method call, you must have had your reasons.