# How to statically assign Dictionary<TKey, TValue> values

Tags: c#, collections

How do I statically assign values to a Dictionary where the value is another class/object.  Like at the following link: [C#: How can Dictionary<K,V> implement ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>> without having Add(KeyValuePair<K,V>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268064/c-how-can-dictionaryk-v-implement-icollectionkeyvaluepairk-v-without-hav)

```
class Settings
{
    public Dictionary<SettingKey, SettingItem> List =
        new Dictionary<SettingKey, SettingItem>()
    {
        {SettingKey.userDBName,{ theValue = "user-name", theID = 1 }},
        {SettingKey.realName,{ theValue = "real-name", theID = 2 }}   
    };
}

enum SettingKey
{
    userDBName,
    realName 
}

class SettingItem
{
    public string theValue { get; set; }
    public int theID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must initialize the objects:

```
public Dictionary<SettingKey, SettingItem> List =
    new Dictionary<SettingKey, SettingItem>()
{
    {SettingKey.userDBName, new SettingItem { theValue = "user-name", theID  = 1 }},
    {SettingKey.realName,   new SettingItem { theValue = "real-name", theID  = 2 }}   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) to set the values of the `SettingItem` objects

```
public Dictionary<SettingKey, SettingItem> List =
    new Dictionary<SettingKey, SettingItem>()
{
    {SettingKey.userDBName, new SettingItem { theValue = "user-name", theID = 1 }},
    {SettingKey.realName, new SettingItem { theValue = "real-name", theID = 2 }}   
};
```